# How to notify multiple active commenters that a question has been updated later?

Tags: discussion, support

Helpful comments from 3-4 people gave me ideas to try, and I have new information and need to update/adjust the question. I could:

1. just re-ask the adjusted question as a new question, linking to the old question for background and mentioning the comments
2. edit the question *by adding the new information at the bottom* in order to keep continuity

I think the second (editing by appending) is better in general.

Will all of the commenters be automatically notified that the question has been changed? I think that this would be good because these are the results of tests done in response to the comments. They may like to see it.

If it's not automatic, then would I have to add one new comment @-ing each commenter in order to notify them? What's a good way to proceed?

Comment: For the part I deleted, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work

Comment: Thank you for the link! - I'll have to read it a few times - this is more confusing than (python) Lambda!

Comment: No, any user with a visible comment **if you include `@theirusername`**, and you can only include one.

Comment: oops - I just fixed my comment. Right, that makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just edit it to the post you would have submitted if you had known before, whoever is interested in the history can look at it.

If one (or more) of the commenters seem interested in seeing the updated post (and maybe helping you), notify them explicitly, individually, with a short summary of what you changed to incorporate their feedback (both comments are probably obsolete shortly after).

---

Notification of new comments goes this way:

If there is only one commenter on your post, that one will be notified.
The owner of the post you comment on and the questions owner are always notified.
You can explicitly notify one additional user (using `@user`) who left a comment, edited, or unilaterally closed (mods and mjölnir-wielders).

Comment: Both answers could be accepted, both are good. I'm choosing this one because the nuance is a better fit for me. @jonrsharpe 's answer causes me to freeze (is my question high enough quality... is it *really* high quality?) I think the best I can do is to ask it *clearly* and let market forces tell me about the quality.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think either of your suggestions is the way to go. I would suggest:

3. Edit the question to be a high-quality question *without worrying about "continuity"*.

New readers then get only the important, up-to-date information, and the old information is still available in the revision history.

---

As for notifying the commenters, I wouldn't worry about it - they may well come back themselves if they're still interested, and pinging them if they're not may serve only to irritate them.

Comment: I would add one caveat that the should not invalidate any answers that are already on their question by changing their question.  In this situation that should not happen but I just wanted to mention it.

Comment: yep! got it. No answers, just some very helpful suggestions.